# How can I search through mongoose schema object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to search through all the comments and return all comments created by a specific user from my mongodb how ever when i try to search the array returned is empty.

I have tried :

```
Comment.find({author: {$elemMatch: {username: req.params.username}}}, (err, foundComments) => {
        // Code goes here
      });
```

The Mongoose Comment Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  discussion:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment',
  }],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  author: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    username: 'String',
    avatar: {
      image: String,
      imageId: String,
    },
  },
  likes: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  }],
  dislikes: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

When I run it I am expecting `foundComments` to be an array `[ array of comments ]` but I just get an empty array `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Comment.find({"author.username":req.params.username});`

Answer (score 0):

```
Comment.find({"username": req.params.username},{"discussion":1,"_id":0})
```